# Can BIOS modify settings of internal gpu?

Tags: bios, gpu

imagine I've got a BIOS and I with it I could edit max VRAM of my internal gpu, is there a BIOS that basically can modify max VRAM? Or is there any option of rewritting BIOS update to modify VRAM? Or can I do it with drivers? Basically I have the questions, so lets answear them!

Comment: There is normally a hard maximum that iGPUs can support.  So even if you had firmware that didn't check for that maximum the hardware wouldn't be able to support the new value.

Comment: @Ramhound so the options are clearly based on the iGPU chip?

Comment: The amount of memory you can share with (reserve for) an iGPU depends on the hardware involved.

Comment: Like I have 16GB RAM and System Shared VRAM is about 6-7GB

Comment: The amount of memory shared with the iGPU shouldn't be a range.  The amount of memory typically is reserved before the OS boots.

Comment: So should I look for modified BIOS?

Comment: [Modern Intel iGPUs are limited to one-half of the system memory that is installed.](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000020962/graphics-drivers.html)  Since you have 16 GB of memory, the maximum amount of memory that can be shared with an Intel GPU is 8 GB, which is your current setting.  Using a different firmware will not make a difference in that case.  I suspect AMD iGPUs will have similar performance, your question is extremely broad, I am unable to answer your question directly. **This limitation is set by the driver not the firmware.**

Comment: @Ramhound in question I mentioned the drivers since I took a look on it. So potentionaly, if I could control the driver I can redefine vram?

Comment: Unless you reduce the scope of your question, I will be unable to answer your question, which means I will be not submitting any more comments. The commentary section is only suppose to be used to clarify the question. The firmware will reserve the amount of memory that can be used, the driver handles everything else, the maximum allowed by the driver is defined by the driver. Which in your question is likely 50% of the system memory, since most iGPUs, are Intel not AMD (with none being Nvidia)